# Asp web page isn't loading from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So I am very new to web hosting. I am simply trying to host my asp website locally, but when I try browsing through IIS it just loads and never shows anything.
Here it is in the directory:
[image]

And here it is in IIS:
[image]

Then I just started the application pool and then clicked browse. Am I not doing something right?

Comment: Have you addressed the path, i.e. physical path of the application pool to the folder where application including your webconfig is located?

Comment: Do you have asp installed on your iis? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Is your website set up as a .net application with Integrated Pipeline mode? http://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver/pipeline-mode-selection/

Comment: Are you using an integrated app pool (required for .net 4+) or is it configured as classic? does your app pool user have all the rights required to start the application (file & db access...)

Comment: Path is correct, Asp is installed, it is currently running integrated pipeline, but I'm not sure if it is set up for that.

Comment: Have you compiled any .cs files on your site? The web forms code behind files need to compiled as a DLL file which will run in release mode, it should located inside `bin` directory. Also you may check application pool configuration to ensure integrated pipeline is running.

Comment: I'm only seeing the dll files that were originally present in the visual studio solution. The .cs files just appear as .cs files outside the bin folder

Comment: I started and stopped some things in the application pools and now when i try browsing my site it just brings up the IIS welcome page

Comment: Please check directory browsing is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I ended up going with was installing UltiDev and running my webpage from that. Honestly it felt far easier to use. I just installed it and selected my files and it worked. I was hoping that's how IIS would work but it still kept throwing errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a browser to view your website locally. Not the file explorer.
You can try `localhost` as url first, if that does not show your site follow the steps below.

1. Open the `hosts` file, located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
   (it could be read only so you may need to change that attribute)
2. Add a line to this file, eg `127.0.0.1  www.medwebtest.com` and save
3. Right click `medwebtest` your website in IIS left pane and select
   `edit bindings`
4. Add the url `www.medwebtest.com` to the site as a new binding.
5. Reopen the browser and navigate to your new url.

Comment: There's no need to add a host header to a site. When omitted, it accepts any host. Also, clicking "Browse..." in the IIS Management Console _does_ open your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, on my new installation of windows.

turns out that I have not installed features for IIS using the following screen

[image]

Once the features have been installed, the website started working again.